# mmap and csv files

Tags: r, mmap

I am trying to understand how to use the package `mmap` 
to access large csv files. More precisely, I'd like to

1. Create a `mmap` object from a `csv` file with `mmap.csv()`;
2. Save the file created by `mmap.csv()` containing the data in binary format;
3. Be able to "map the binary data back to R" using the function `mmap()`.

Achieving 1. and 2. is easy: just use `mmap.cv()` and save the `tempfile()`
that contains the binary data, or modify `mmap.cv()` to accept an extra parameter
as output file (and modify the line `tmpstruct <- tempfile()` accordingly).
What I am having trouble with is 3. In particular, I need to construct a 
C-struct for the records in the binary data from the `mmap` object. 
Here is a simple reproducible example:

```
# create mmap object with its file
library(mmap)
data(cars)

m <- as.mmap(cars, file="cars.Rmap")
colnames(m) <- colnames(cars)
str(m) 
munmap(m)
```

The information from `str()` can be used to construct the C-struct
`record.struct` that allows mapping the binary file `cars.Rmap` 
via the function mmap.

```
> str(m)
<mmap:temp.Rmap>  (struct) struct [1:50, 1:2] 4 ...
  data         :<externalptr> 
  bytes        : num 400
  filedesc     : Named int 27
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "temp.Rmap"
  storage.mode :List of 2
 $ speed:Classes 'Ctype', 'int'  atomic (0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "bytes")= int 4
  .. ..- attr(*, "signed")= int 1
 $ dist :Classes 'Ctype', 'int'  atomic (0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "bytes")= int 4
  .. ..- attr(*, "signed")= int 1
 - attr(*, "bytes")= int 8
 - attr(*, "offset")= int [1:2] 0 4
 - attr(*, "signed")= logi NA
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "Ctype" "struct"
  pagesize     : num 4096
  dim          :NULL
```

In this case, we need two 4-byte integers:

```
# load from disk
record.struct <- struct(speed = integer(),  # int32(), 4 byte int
                        dist  = integer()   # int32(), 4 byte int
                        )
m <- mmap("temp.Rmap", mode=record.struct)
```

Inferring the right C-struct can be very impractical for "wide" csv files (i.e. files with tens or hundreds of columns). Here is my question:
*How can one construct `record.struct` directly 
from the mmap object `m`?*

Comment: I don't know anything about mmap, but I just wanted to make sure you know that there's a vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mmap/vignettes/mmap.pdf

Comment: @XuWang: thanks, I am aware of the vignette. That's what got me through 1 and 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A more or less complete example of what you are asking - using mmap and mmap.csv

```
data(mtcars)
tmp <- tempfile()
write.csv(mtcars, tmp)
m <- mmap.csv(tmp)   # mmap in the csv
head(m)
                    X  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 Mazda RX4           21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 Datsun 710          22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6 Valiant             18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1


st <- m$storage.mode

## since m is already mmap'd as a binary, we'll use that here - but you'd store this
m1 <- mmap(attr(m$filedesc, "names"), mode=st, extractFUN=as.data.frame)

head(m1)
                    X  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 Mazda RX4           21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 Datsun 710          22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6 Valiant             18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

As a previous answer mentions, m$storage.mode is the **mode** you are needing.

You could go one step further and store the mode in a file using some naming convention of your devising.  You could also create a custom binary object utilizing the **len** and **off** args to mmap.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I didn't realize `m$storage.mode` could be used directly

Comment: That's much slicker.  Any chance you're same Jeff Ryan that authored the `mmap` package?  :)

Comment: Answering myself: yes - and there are some nice articles on [your site](http://www.lemnica.com/esotericR/).  Most of your packages if not all of them are on my list to try out.  I'm glad to see you're on SO.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I am giving another answer because the first answer is for the primary question (*How can one construct `record.struct` directly from the mmap object `m`?*), however, I think it's also possible to address the predicate: "Inferring the right C-struct can be very impractical for "wide" csv files (i.e. files with tens or hundreds of columns)."  My motivation is to dispel the idea that type information is hard to obtain for CSV files.  :)

Assuming that the data is regular (i.e. atomic per column, which it has to be if it was going to get memory mapped), then you could simply do this:

```
tmpDF <- read.csv(myFile, nrow = 10)
myClasses <- rapply(tmpDF, typeof)
```

Thus, you read in only a small amount of information and let R determine classes for you.  You may need to address the `stringsAsFactors` issue, i.e. via `read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
varClasses <- rapply(m$storage.mode, typeof)
```

Here's what I get:

```
> rapply(m$storage.mode, typeof)
    speed     dist
 "double" "double"
```

(This is due to `cars` being stored as doubles in my version of R.  Results match yours when the type is changed to integers - see Update 1, below.)

Using this to create the `struct` object is simply a matter of replacing these types with the appropriate C types (e.g. changing `int` to `integer`), which can be done via a list lookup, and then you could use `paste` to create the appropriate list of arguments.

---

Here's what `m` looks like for me, using the same commands as you gave:

```
> str(m)
<mmap:/tmp/Rtmpz...>  (struct) struct [1:50, 1:2] 4 ...
  data         :<externalptr> 
  bytes        : num 800
  filedesc     : Named int 3
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "/tmp/RtmpzGwIDT/file77aa9d47"
  storage.mode :List of 2
 $ speed:Classes 'Ctype', 'double'  atomic (0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "bytes")= int 8
  .. ..- attr(*, "signed")= int 1
 $ dist :Classes 'Ctype', 'double'  atomic (0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "bytes")= int 8
  .. ..- attr(*, "signed")= int 1
 - attr(*, "bytes")= int 16
 - attr(*, "offset")= int [1:2] 0 8
 - attr(*, "signed")= logi NA
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "Ctype" "struct"
  pagesize     : num 4096
  dim          :NULL
```

---

Update 1: When I explicitly converted `cars` to integers, and ensured the object was a data frame (i.e. `cars2 <- as.data.frame(apply(cars, 2, as.integer)); colnames(cars2) = colnames(cars)`), everything works out, and the `rapply` produces `"integer"`, as expected.

Update 2: Here's hack at creating the internal arguments to pass to `struct()`:

```
oTypes  = rapply(m$storage.mode, typeof)
lNames  = names(oTypes)
lTypes  = as.character(oTypes)
lTypes  = paste(lTypes,'()', sep = "")
lArgs   = paste(lNames, lTypes, sep = "=", collapse = ",")
```

It's an approximation, because I suspect that `lTypes` needs to be converted from R to C types.

Comment: Thanks Iterator. I accepted with Jeff's answer because of the direct use of `storage.mode`.

Comment: Thanks for asking a good question.  I was sure there had to be a better way than to wrangle the types as I did.  :)  Still, it looked fun to try and see where the the data types could be obtained.